# macOS Sierra Installer not launching: The application “Install macOS Sierra” can’t be opened

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

So, I downloaded the second GM before the public release, tried to open it and got this error: The application “Install macOS Sierra” can’t be opened.
I then downloaded the public release from the Mac AppStore, same problem.

---

I tried using `chmod +x /..../Contents/MacOS/Install/InstallAssistant`, made the app open but immediately stops responding.

---

Note: I did download both files from another Mac, put them on USB and brought them home, I always used this method and it worked, not working now.
I'm on a late 2013 MacBook Pro (15 inch).

Any suggestions or ideas on why this error is occurring?

Comment: The app is corrupted or locked to a specific mac. You could try figuring out if it's broken with the 'file' and 'otool' commands or launch it from a shell and check the exit status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it sounds stupid, but I compressed the file and transferred it to my personal Mac via USB, decompressed and it worked, but seriously couldn't find out what was causing that error.